# Java downloader library

Tags: java

Is there any downloader library(api) for java? What i found is "almost" a downloader library but i also can do other task, it is `common-io`'s `FileUtils.copyUrlToFile()` method. It handle all io operation(create directory for example .../files/file.txt so downloaded file is .../files/file.txt, etc). I wish someone can tell me a library that support all io operation required to download a file and with `pause()`, `resume()` and `stop()` method and also it will work with `JProgressBar` easily when downloading multiple files.